# Busybox support for ANSI escape codes?

Tags: escape-characters, busybox, documentation

I am working on some scripts that must run inside of initramfs. One of the scripts does an operation that takes a few minutes, so I want to display a nice progress bar that updates in-place, add in a little bit of colored text, etc. Just make the interface a little nicer for the end user.

Now, most of my scripting experience is writing scripts for bash and I've used ANSI escape codes many times in that context, but busybox seems to handle some ANSI escape codes in a non-standard way. Based on this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters), the escape code `\e[1m` should make text bold, and indeed in a bash shell the command `echo -e "\e[1mansi test"` does just that. In a busybox shell, that same echo command outputs black text with the regular font weight.

For another example, the command `echo -e "\e[3mansi test"` should output italic text. In bash, it does. In busybox, it instead outputs green text, which is usually done with the `\e[32m` escape code (yes I made sure I didn't typo the command).

From what I'm seeing, busybox does not seem to fully honor the standard ANSI escape codes and instead seems to have some alternate interpretation of them, but I cannot find documentation on this anywhere.

Does anybody know what's going on here and where I can find some documentation on how busybox interprets ANSI escape codes?